# React + Jest infinite loop only in test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I'm having the following problem with my react + nextJS project...

The component is something like this:

```
import React, { FC, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import InputMask, { Props } from 'react-input-mask';
import {
  getPayersDetails,
  PayerCompany,
  PayerContact,
  PayerDocuments,
} from 'services';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

import { Field, Loading, Page, Tooltip } from 'components';
import { Button, IconButton, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import { SvgSelfCheckout } from 'images';
import {
  FaEdit,
  FaFileInvoiceDollar,
  FaUserCheck,
  FaUserAltSlash,
} from 'react-icons/fa';

import theme from 'styles/theme';
import * as S from './styles';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { PAYER_HOME } from 'src/routes';

const PayersDetails: FC = () => {
  const [payerCompany, setPayerCompany] = useState<PayerCompany[]>([]);
  const [payerContact, setPayerContact] = useState<PayerContact[]>([]);
  const [payerDocument, setPayerDocument] = useState<PayerDocuments[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [isActivePayer, setIsActivePayer] = useState(false);

  const router = useRouter();

  const getPayerDetails = useCallback(async (payerId: number) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const payerDetails = await getPayersDetails(payerId);
    setPayerCompany(payerDetails.payerCompany);
    setPayerDocument(payerDetails.payerDocument);
    setPayerContact(payerDetails.payerContact);

    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) {
      return;
    }
    const payerId = router.query.payerId as string;

    try {
      const safePayerId = parseInt(payerId);
      getPayerDetails(safePayerId);
    } catch (e) {
      router.push(PAYER_HOME);
      return;
    }
  }, [getPayerDetails, router]);

  const contact = payerContact.length > 0 ? payerContact[0] : null;

  const mobilePhone = payerContact
    .filter(contact => contact.contactType.contactTypeName === 'mobile')
    .map(contact => contact.value)[0];

  return (
    <Page
      title="Detalhes do pagador"
      pageTitle="Detalhes do pagador"
      pageSubtitle="Dados pessoais"
      pageSubitleColor={`${theme.palette.primary.light}`}
    >
      {loading ? (
        <Loading show={loading} />
      ) : (
        <Formik
          enableReinitialize={true}
          initialValues={{
            name: contact?.contactName,
            email: contact?.value,
          }}
          onSubmit={() => console.log('onSumit')}
        >
          ....
          )}
        </Formik>
      )}
    </Page>
  );
};

export default PayersDetails;
```

And I'm trying to test it with the following code:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { getCompany } from 'services/companies';
import { getPayersDetails } from 'services/payers';
import PayersImport from '.';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

jest.mock('services/payers', () => ({
  __esModule: true, // this property makes it work
  default: 'mockedDefaultExport',
  getPayersDetails: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    route: '/',
    pathname: '',
    query: '',
    asPath: '',
  })),
}));

describe('payers details layout', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  describe('when rendering', () => {
    let getPayersDetailsMock;

    beforeEach(() => {
      getPayersDetailsMock = {
        ...
      };
      getPayersDetails.mockResolvedValue(getPayersDetailsMock);

      useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
        route: '/',
        pathname: '',
        isReady: true,
        query: { payerId: 1 },
        asPath: '',
      }));

      render(<PayersImport />);
    });

    it('Calls details api with the correct id', () => {
      expect(getPayersDetails).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    });
  });
});
```

The issue is:
The component load ok when we go to a browser, but when I run it on jest I get the following error:

```
console.error
    Warning: An update to PayersDetails inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at PayersDetails (/home/thiago/finnet/repos/welcome/apps/lunapay-front/src/layouts/Payers/PayersDetails/index.tsx:29:43)

      43 |     setPayerContact(payerDetails.payerContact);
      44 |
    > 45 |     setLoading(false);
         |     ^
      46 |   }, []);
      47 |
      48 |   useEffect(() => {
```

I get it is only a warning and it wouldn't be a problem for me, but the issue is that it goes into a infinite loop trying to render again.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `jest` fall into an infinite loop with `useEffect`, if that is your case, you can make a mock of it

```
import React from 'react'

const mockUseEffect = jest.fn()

jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation(mockUseEffect)
```

and try with that and/or adapt to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, but it was not the best solution.

Basically the render was being triggered by the `<Loading />` component being rendered again.

What I did was just adding a new property telling me if it was already fetched and canceling the loop.

```
const [payerDetailsResponse, setPayerDetailsResponse] =
    useState<PayerDetailsResponse | null>(null);
  const [payerCompany, setPayerCompany] = useState<PayerCompany[]>([]);
  const [payerContact, setPayerContact] = useState<PayerContact[]>([]);
  const [payerDocument, setPayerDocument] = useState<PayerDocuments[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [isActivePayer, setIsActivePayer] = useState(false);

  const router = useRouter();

  const getPayerDetails = useCallback(async (payerId: number) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const payerDetails = await getPayersDetails(payerId);
    setPayerDetailsResponse(payerDetails);
    setPayerCompany(payerDetails.payerCompany);
    setPayerDocument(payerDetails.payerDocument);
    setPayerContact(payerDetails.payerContact);

    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (payerDetailsResponse) {
      return;
    }

    if (!router.isReady) {
      return;
    }
    const payerId = router.query.payerId as string;

    try {
      const safePayerId = parseInt(payerId);

      getPayerDetails(safePayerId);
    } catch (e) {
      router.push(PAYER_HOME);
      return;
    }
  }, [router, getPayerDetails]);
```

Sorry not to be able to help more, but that was a solution for my problem :)